# Deriving the Nautilus shell spiral equation

Tags: polar-coordinates

Suppose I need to estimate the cross section of a Nautilus shell, which is famously approximated by a logarithmic spiral, $r=ae^{b\theta}$.
[image: Nautilus shell spiral]

The cross-section of this spiral could be found by integrating over the last revolution.

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{6\pi}^{8\pi}r^2~d\theta$$

But I am struggling with finding $a$ and $b$. We can measure the width of the shell, $w$, along the horizontal axis, and the hight, $h$, along the vertical axis. How do we then find $a$ and $b$ via $w$ and $h$?

Comment: I'm interested in this what are variables a and b representing?

Comment: @Nick just coefficients in the polar equation that govern the shape of the spiral, how quickly it coils away from the centre, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A better method is to convert the $\,(r,\theta)\,$ data points to do a linear fit of
$\, \log(r) = \log(a)+b\theta.\,$

Answer (score 0):

If the total number of rotations are 4, you have a set of 2 equations here:
$$w = a(e^{8\pi b} - e^{7\pi b})$$
$$h = a(e^{7.5\pi b} - e^{6.5\pi b})$$
Further calculation of solving for $a$ and $b$ is trivial.

Comment: Shouldn't there be pluses instead of minues?